# Integration with respect to finite variation processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, lebesgue-integral, stochastic-integrals

Hey can anyone explain me (or recommend a book) how we construct stochastic integral of (not necessarily continuous) process $H$ with respect to process with finite variation (also not continuous)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stochastic integral is usually constructed for adapted càglàd (continuous on the left, limit on the right) processes as integrands and semimartingales $\big($which are càdlàg (continuous on the right, limit on the left) processes and include the FV-processes$\big)$ as integrator by using predictable simple processes and the property that the predictable simple processes are dense under the ucp-topology in the set of adapted càglàd processes. From this you can extend it to a bigger class of integrands. But all this you can read for example in the book of Protter ("Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations").

By the way, for integrators which are FV-processes you can also directly use the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration path-by-path. A theorem states (also in the book I recomended) that the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral and the stochastic integral are indistinguishable in that case.

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me where can I find well described construction of Lebesque-Stieltjes integral?

Comment: Sry, I don't know a good book describing this. But there is a lot of information about this on wikipedia for [Riemann-Stieltjes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) and [Lebesgue-Stieltjes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration). Maybe you find one in the references.