# Definition of semimartingale and stochastic integration

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Hey I found two definitions of semimartingale. One states that semimartingale is a sum of local martingale and FV process and the second one states that semimartingale is a sum of FV process and locally square integrable martingale. Are these definitions equivalent? I would like to define stochastic integral of caglad process with respect to semimartingale. Can I define this integral as the sum of Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral and integral w.r.t locally square integrable process? Or I have to define this integral using the first definition? What is the difference? Is this integral well defined? I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Do you just consider continuous semimartingale or the general càdlàg-case?

Comment: General case, I want to define stochastic integral so that the integral of caglad proces with repsect to proces $e^X$ where $X$ is a Levy process make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your two definitions: I know the first one for **classical semimartingales** (or just **semimartingales**). The second one is the defintion of **decomposable** processes (e.g. in the book of Protter Ch.II,3).

The two definitions are equivalent: As every process which is locally a square integrable martingale is of course also a local martingale, all processes satisfying the second definition also satisfy the first definition. For the reverse you have to use the Fundamental Theorem of Local Martingales (e.g. in the book of Protter Ch.III,6,Th.25). This states that every local martingale can be written as the sum of two local martingales, whereas one of them is a FV process and the other has bounded jumps. The local martingale with bounded jumps is a locally bounded martingale und thus locally a square integrable martingale.

To your second question: As the FV part can be used for a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral the answer is YES (for a FV process the stochastic and the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral are indistinguishable, see Protter Ch.II,5,Th.17). Since you are only integrating càglàd processes the integral is well defined.

Comment: Thanks, I use book by P. Medvegyev ,,Stochatic integration theory'' and I don't understand why in caglad case the definition is well defined. The decomposition of semimartingale as a sum of FV process and locally square integrable is not unique. Which theorem guarantee that for any decomposition the integral is the same?

Comment: You usually define the stochastic integral for a càdlàg semimartingale as integrators and adapted càglàd processes as integrands. This is done like I described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4045812/integration-with-respect-to-finite-variation-processes/4047120#4047120). As I don't know your book, I can't say anything about the way in your book and thus I can't tell you the reasons. But when you define the stochastic integral as described, the decomposition of a semimartingale is not relevant. Thus it is also not relevant that the decomposition is not unique.

Comment: The stochastic integral $H\bullet X$ regarding a semimartingale $X=M+A$ ($M$ loc. mart., $A$ FV proc.) is a semimartingale again and can thus be decomposed (not uniquely) as $H\bullet X=H\bullet M +H\bullet A$. If you make the decomposition before you integrate and choose for your FV part $A$ the Lebesque-Stieltjes integral $\int H\mathrm d A$ instead of the stochastic integral $H\bullet A$, the theorem I mentioned in the answers guarantees you that they are indistinguishable. So it makes no difference. They are indistinguishable, but the decomposition is still not unique.

Comment: Simply think about an integer $z$, e.g. $z=-15$. If you consider decomposition as a sum of a integer $a$ and a natural number $b$, i.e. $z=a+b$, it is not unique, e.g. $a_1=-16, b_1=1$ and $a_2=-20, b_2=5$. If now you do anything with it, e.g. square, you can make a decomposition again (which is not unique). But the way $z^2:=2ab +(a^2+b^2)$ the power of 2 is definied here guarantees you that both are the same: $(-16+1)^2=-32+257=225=-200+425$.